# Updating SharePoint Online items using SOAP/XML API from outside of SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, soap

We need to update (CRUD) SharePoint Online list items from a stand alone application outside of SharePoint from an external company.

This application uses Soap/XML calls to call SP.

The (external) application has been able to connect and update an On-Premises SharePoint 2010 list with no problems, but now we are migrating to SharePoint Online.

The external application **can connect to and view list items** but always throws an error when we try to *update an item in the list* on SharePoint Online

Here is the (redacted) Soap request body and response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:UpdateListItems>
         <soap:listName>XXXXXX GUID</soap:listName>
         <soap:updates>
            <Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" ViewName="XXX GUID CUT">
   <Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">
      <Field Name="ID">1002</Field>
      <Field Name="Received">1</Field>
      <Field Name="COMSBarcode">RL101150</Field>
      <Field Name="DateReceived">2020-03-03</Field>
      <Field Name="ReceivedBy">andras boros</Field>
      <Field Name="DefectsFaults" />
      <Field Name="Description">This is Box 20/1</Field>
   </Method>
   <Method ID="2" Cmd="Update">
      <Field Name="ID">1003</Field>
      <Field Name="Received">1</Field>
      <Field Name="COMSBarcode">RL101151</Field>
      <Field Name="DateReceived">2020-03-03</Field>
      <Field Name="ReceivedBy">andras boros</Field>
      <Field Name="DefectsFaults" />
      <Field Name="Description">This is Box 20/2</Field>
   </Method>
   <Method ID="3" Cmd="Update">
      <Field Name="ID">1004</Field>
      <Field Name="Received">1</Field>
      <Field Name="COMSBarcode">RL101152</Field>
      <Field Name="DateReceived">2020-03-03</Field>
      <Field Name="ReceivedBy">andras boros</Field>
      <Field Name="DefectsFaults" />
      <Field Name="Description">This is Box20/3</Field>
   </Method>
</Batch>
         </soap:updates>
      </soap:UpdateListItems>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
4:02
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <UpdateListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
         <UpdateListItemsResult>
            <Results>
               <Result ID="1,Update">
                  <ErrorCode>0x81020026</ErrorCode>
                  <ErrorText>The list that is referenced here no longer exists.</ErrorText>
                  <z:row ows_Title="I changed it online (Andras Boros)" ows_T_x002d_Code="X91" ows_BoxNo="20.0000000000000" 
                  {TL:DR}
                  ows_SMTotalFileCount="1002;#0" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema"/>
               </Result>
               {TL:DR}
             </Results>
            </UpdateListItemsResult>
        </UpdateListItemsResponse>
    </Body>
</soap:envelope/>
```

Is it possible to update SharePoint Online list items from a standalone webapp in a completely different doamin?

And how would we go about handling authentication.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused because the URL & WSDL were for the top site SharePoint, rather than the specific sub-site.

Once we provided the sub-site url/wsdl the external app started working correctly

The error "`The List That is Referenced Here no Longer Exists`" is thrown when you try to reference the wrong subsite when you create the web reference to Lists.asmx web service.

"If your site URL is `http://my_share_point_site, the list.asmx can be found at http://my_share_point_site/sites/main/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?WSDL` and use that URL to reference the API and some things might work.

When we attempt to update a list found under some sub_site, your updates will silently fail. You have to reference `http://my_share_point_site/sites/main/sub_site/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?WSDL` for updates to your list."

Here is a blog post about the issue:
[SharePoint: The List That is Referenced Here no Longer Exists](http://alsaydi.blogspot.com/2011/04/sharepoint-list-that-is-referenced-here.html)

Here is a thread about calling lists.asmx in SharePoint Online which we also found helpful:
[How to call (_vti_bin) SOAP web service in SharePoint Online 2013 from dot net web application](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103493/how-to-call-vti-bin-soap-web-service-in-sharepoint-online-2013-from-dot-net-w)

Also, outside of SharePoint Online, it's suggested to use SharePoint Online CSOM instead of Lists.asmx, Lists.asmx is the old way mainly for SharePoint 2010:

[How To Read Various Objects Using SharePoint Online Client Side Object Model (CSOM)](https://www.fmtconsultants.com/sharepoint-online-client-side-object-model/)

[Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)